# VirtualBox crashes with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I've tried it with many different configuration changes. Eventually I'm using now the stock config with 3D support and 128 MB graphics memory. The installation of Ubuntu crashes and I get the following log:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=N6vw9mMe

I have 8 GB ram in my computer, and I've dedicated 4 GB for the VM.

Thank you for any efforts.

Comment: Actually better suited for AskUbuntu, don't you think?

Comment: It was automatically moved to here from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved by reducing the memory of the machine to 512 MB. I don't know why, but that worked.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The latest virtualbox does not yet support ubuntu 12.04, only up to 11.04.  Latest version of vmplayer works fine with 12.04 however, so you may want to try that, and then use VB to run the vm to see if that would work.

Comment: This is not true. The problem was solved by reducing the memory of the machine to 512 MB. I don't know why, but that worked. Anyway thanks for the try :)